# If a matrix is not invertible, then is it that $N(A) \neq \varnothing$, or $N(A) \neq \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N(A)$ be the null space of $A$

Then if $A$ is not invertible, is it that

$N(A) \neq \varnothing$, or $N(A) \neq \{0\}$

I am confused about a lecture I saw where the person said "$A$ is not invertible when the null space is not empty", and I know that $0$ is always in the Nullspace, first expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: You are right, the null space is never non-empty. So $N(A) \neq \{0\}$ is right.

Answer (score 2):

You caught an error there.

The null space is a subspace;   thus always contains $\vec0$.